# call microsoft graph using the logged in user

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I created ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework) with work/School Authentication through Azure. 
When I run it, it asks users to login which is as expected.

On the other hand, to call Microsoft Graph and get the phoho, e.g. GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`, I need to get an access token. I know ho to get access token using username and password, but system did not capture what username and password the user entered already, so this requires that system will ask user again to put his password which is strange!!

If I use a separate defined username and password, I will lose the ability of using `me` in the api call parameters, as this becomes another user. Also, I know I can call Graph using client ID instead of username and password, but again I will not be able to call any API using `me` parameter

Is there any way to get the access token by using the current logged in user without asking him to enter credentials again? I don't know if I drive the concept in a wrong way, but the target is to call Graph API using `me` and without asking user to submit credentials twice, but by taking advantage of the logged in user!

Comment: I suggest reviewing https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2#scope-of-this-tutorial as this should provide the experience you want. If you are already doing this, please provide details of the browser and device you use for the webapp. Ideally, I'd expect your webapp to get SSO without a prompt for credentials using a PRT as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-primary-refresh-token . But this is dependant on the device and browser used to access the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the people who created Asp.Net Web Application project, with Azure Work or school authentication, and worrying about how to use the authentication of the logged-in user, to get an access token and call Microsoft Graph, without asking the use to re-enter his credentials, the clear answer after few search is:

***DO NOT THINK ABOUT REFRESH TOKEN.***

Yes, usually the concept is to capture the refresh token, and use it in the next call to get a new access token to call an api. But `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`, which is used in this setup, is making it more simple. This package simplify the whole process and gives you two method to call:

`AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` (StartupAuth.cs): which is used in the startup of the application to ask the user to login and get the first access token, WITHOUT REFRESH TOKEN!

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync`: gives you directly a new access token for the same logged in user. You may not be noticing, *like me*, that a new UserInfo.aspx page was added to the project during the creation, to show you how to get new access token for every API call you are doing. Just refer to this page code behind, to understand the whole concept.

I hope this clarify the confusion, as usually, users will be thinking towards the refresh code instead!

Answer (score 0):

In short:

Login call:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize returns a `code`.

Request access to scopes, among the parameters `code`:
https://login.microsoftonIine.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.O/token

From this you get an `access_token` and a `refresh_token` which you use against `https://graph.microsoft.com`. The `access_token` can be reused and a new one can be requested by sending in the `refresh_token`, which is long-lived.

EDIT: 
I am running this in Blazor serverside, but I hope this helps. 
In my _Host.cshtml i am gathering acess_token and refresh_token.

```
        var tokens = new InitialApplicationState()
        {
            access_token    = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
            refresh_token   = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"),
            id_token        = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token"),
            token_type      = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("token_type"),
            expires_at      = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at")
        };
```

I use access_token in the queries agains Graph

```
       public MyGraphService(MyTokenProvider _token)
        {
            token = _token;
        }

        private readonly MyTokenProvider token = null;

        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider: null);

        private List<HeaderOption> requstHeaders()
        {
            return new List<HeaderOption>() { new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken) };
        }

        public async Task<Microsoft.Graph.User> GetMe()
        {   
            User me = await graphClient.Me.Request(requstHeaders()).GetAsync();
            return me;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. you are here explaining the flow rather than answering my specific question. I'm using the built in classes that are created by visual studio when I chose to create asp.net application with Azure Active Directory authentication. this will use the `AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                              code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId).Result;` which does not have a refresh token. I do not want to rebuild the solution from scratch

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I have added some code. Hope this helps you further. In addition, I catch exceptions telling me that access_token is expired and run a refresh process using httpClient.

Comment: Sorry for telling you again, that I'm not looking for new implementation. I was asking about how to, using the existing authentication mechanism, get a new access token on every call. you answer was ok, but not to my question. I posted an answer if you are interested.